# control structure, repetition exercise: How to get the sum of the digits of a number?

Tags: java, console-application

Guys can you please help me answer this exercise using for loop without using string methods.

*Write a program that prompts the user to input an integer and then outputs both the individual digits of the number and the sum of the digits. For example, the program should output the individual digits of 3456 as 3 4 5 6 and the sum as 18,and output the individual digits of -2345 as 2 3 4 5 and the sum as 14.*

This is the code:

```
package MyPackage;

import java.util.*;

public class Integer 
{
    public static void main(String args[])
    {   
       Scanner console = new Scanner (System.in);
       int input;
       int sum = 0;
       int num1 = 0;
       int counter = 1;
       String num = "";

       System.out.print("enter a number: ");
       input = console.nextInt();

       if (input == (-input))       
           {

               input = input * (-1);
               num = String.valueOf(input);
               num1 = num.length();
               System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");

               for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++ )
               {
                  String var = num.substring(i,counter);
                  int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
                  System.out.print(var + " ");
                  sum = sum + var1;
                  counter++;
               }
               System.out.println();
               System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);

         }

        else                    
            {   
               num = String.valueOf(input);
               num1 = num.length();
               System.out.print("the digits of " + input + " are: ");

               for (int i = 0; i < num1; i++ )
               {
                   String var = num.substring(i,counter);
                   int var1 = Character.getNumericValue(var.charAt(0));
                   System.out.print(var + " ");
                   sum = sum + var1;
                   counter++;
               }
               System.err.println();
               System.out.println("the sum is: " + sum);

         }
  }
}
```

Comment: Hint: Use modulus % and integer division / until your input is zero and add the modulus remainders.

Comment: here is my sample code...i used string methods here and convert inputs to strings to get the individual digits and convert again into int to get the sum...is there a way to code this using only integers or without using string?

Comment: You are getting input as int via `console.nextInt()`. No need to convert that to String. Just divide it my 10 and get the mode. That will strip out individual digits, loop it until the number becomes 0  and then add it up..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Iterating all the digits **from right to left** is easy enough - you just keep dividing by 10 and keeping the remainder.
Since you need to print them from **left to right**, but there don't seem to be any constraint on the memory usage, you could just keep them in a list, and print it backwards:

```
int num = ...; // inputed from user
List<Integer> digits = new LinkedList<>();
int sum = 0;

// Extract the digits and the sum
while (num != 0) {
    int digit = num % 10;
    digits.add (digit);
    sum += digit;
    num /= 10;
}

// Print backwards:
System.out.print ("The digits are: ");
for (int i = digits.size() - 1; i >= 0; --i) {
    System.out.print (digits.get(i) + " ");
}
System.out.println();
System.out.println("Their sum is: " + sum);
```